# How to change virtual resolution for the webView for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, wkwebview

Is there a way to change a virtual resolution of the webView component? On iPhones width is only 320 pixels, which is very aweful as there is not much that can be put on screen. Especially when trying to design a webapp which works on desktop/android/iOS.

I have checked, current android devices have around 400 virtual pixels per width which is enough for the content to be displayed correctly, however even iPhone 12 pro provides only 320px.

I am hoping there is a solution to change resolution before we move on to changing the whole UI of the web app just so it can fit the 320px.